# How to read bytes from a file

Tags: file, stream, prolog, byte, file-read

I'm attempting to read a file into a list of bytes in prolog, using swipl version 8.0.3.

```
:- use_module(library(readutil)).

try_read_byte(File):-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    get_byte(Stream, B),
    print(B).

try_read_char(File):-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    get_char(Stream, C),
    print(C).
```

`try_read_char` succeeds, but when I call `try_read_byte`, I get an error:

```
ERROR: No permission to read bytes from TEXT stream `<stream>(0x56413a06a2b0)'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] get_byte(<stream>(0x56413a06a2b0),_9686)
ERROR:    [8] try_read_byte("test.pl") at /home/justin/code/decompile/test.pl:5
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

From reviewing the source code/documentation (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=error), it seems as if this is something like a type error, but I'm not able to figure out what to do based on that.

Comment: I would also not mind pointers to a better way to read a list of bytes from a file, as it seems surprising that I'd need to write that in pure prolog, rather than using a library predicate.

Comment: You need to say `open(File, read, D, [type(binary)])`. But do you really want bytes? (this is not specific to SWI)

Comment: Thanks, post this as an answer, and I can accept it. 

I'm trying to write a parser for a binary format, so I think getting bytes really is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read binary, you need to specify the option `type(binary)`. Otherwise `get_byte` raises a `permission_error` as specified by the standard (section 8.13.1.3). This can be confusing as the user might be checking for correct permissions, which has nothing to do with the actual source of the problem.

```
try_read_byte(File):-
    open(File, read, Stream, [type(binary)])),
    get_byte(Stream, B),
    write(B).
```

I just tried this with Scryer Prolog, and it prints the first byte of the file as expected.